# How is 'new T()' or 'typeof(T)' compiled?

Tags: c#, generics, compilation, jit

I do not know an awful lot about IL, the CLR, or the JIT compiler. But what I've read is that generic code is compiled to generic IL, and only the JIT compiler eventually instantiates the generic code with the provided concrete type arguments. I makes sense that there might be **multiple versions** of some generic code fragment (method or class), because they have **different representations in memory**. For example, there is one version for each value type (or set thereof), and another for the set of all reference types. The type checking has already happened, so the JIT compiler is just concerned about representation.

However, what about statements like `new T()` or `typeof(T)`, where `T` is a generic type argument in some surrounding class/method? My assumption is that these statements have to be re-compiled for absolutely every possible concrete type parameter for `T`, since the code actually is different for each of them. If you don't know `T`, you also cannot know which constructor to call in `new T()`, right?

It would be great to get some insight into this.

Comment: This is something you can see with a disassembler, like ildasm.exe.  It is generic at the IL level without either the jitter or the CLR having to break a sweat over the code generation.  new T() calls Activator.CreateInstance<>(), typeof(T) calls Type.GetTypeFromHandle().  Plain documented methods.

Comment: So this type handle is like a little object stored alongside the instance of a generic type, such that it can be queried at runtime and based on its value (i.e. like reflection) a new instance of that type can be created?

Comment: It is named RuntimeTypeHandle in the framework.  Just a pointer.